# Jsp render variable with jsp tags inside

Tags: jsp, tags, render

In the JSPX page I use custom tag and this works fine

```
<body>
    <ui:image name="nameOfImage"/>
</body>
```

However If I put the `<ui:image name="nameOfImage"/>` into variable `body`
This will not work

```
<body>
    ${body}
</body>
```

The question is how to ask JSP render engine to render jsp tags inside variable?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to do that directly. The closest thing to what you are asking is a custom tag I once encountered from the [Eval taglib](http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/evaltag.htm). It's supposed to be something similar to JavaScript's `eval()` (or so they say).

Maybe you could look into it and see how it does its thing and borrow some ideas.

**EDIT:** It didn't occur to me yesterday, but you might use JSTL to do something similar, although this only works inside the JSP(X), if you want to set the content of the variable somewhere higher (like a controller) it won't work as it won't get evaluated but just output-ed as String.

The `<c:set>` allows you to evaluate some content and place the result in a variable which you can then reuse:

```
<c:set var="body">
   <ui:image name="nameOfImage"/>
</c:set>
....
<body>
    ${body}
</body>
```

Comment: @Mykola Golubyev: you're welcome! I've edited my answer to add another option, but don't know if that is what you are looking for. What are you trying to do anyway?